# How to get the current project name in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I want to send an email to myself when an exception is thrown. Using StackFrame object, I am able to get File Name, Class Name and even class method that throw the Exception, but I also need to know the project name as many of my ASP.NET project has the same file name, class name and method.

This is my code:

```
    public static string JndGetEmailTextForDebuggingExceptionError(this Exception Ex)
    {
        StackFrame sf = Ex.JndGetStackFrame();

        string OutputHTML =         "<i><b><u>For Developer Use Only: </u></b></i>"                                                 + "<br>" + 
                                                                                                                                      "<br>" +
                                    "Project Name:   "  + HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name + "<br>" + //Under discussion
                                    "File Name:      "  + sf.GetFileName()                                                          + "<br>" +
                                    "Class Name:     "  + sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType                                              + "<br>" +
                                    "Method Name:    "  + sf.GetMethod()                                                            + "<br>" +
                                    "Line Number:    "  + sf.GetFileLineNumber()                                                    + "<br>" +
                                    "Line Column:    "  + sf.GetFileColumnNumber()                                                  + "<br>" +
                                    "Error Message:  "  + Ex.Message                                                                + "<br>" +
                                    "Inner Message : "  + Ex.InnerException.Message                                                 + "<br>";

        return OutputHTML;
    }
```

Thanks ALL.

Comment: That sounds confusing. Why are the file names and class names the same in different projects?

Comment: @TimS. - File: HomeController.cs; Class: HomeController; Method: Index. This is the template that most VS users get with a new MVC project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by project, calling assembly? Should be in the stack trace unless you've destroyed it with throw(ex). Some sort of application logger and attach the output would be a better choice. You could queue them instead of of getting a mullion emails when something goes horrible.

Comment: It is in separated Assembly.

Comment: I think that I can use the full file path to determine which project is it, however, I want to know if there is any better way to just get the project name only.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) if you have your logging code in a separate library assembly, and call directly from your ASP.NET assembly to your library, and you mark the method so that it won't be inlined:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static string JndGetEmailTextForDebuggingExceptionError(this Exception Ex)
{
    StackFrame sf = Ex.JndGetStackFrame();

    string OutputHTML =         "<i><b><u>For Developer Use Only: </u></b></i>"                    + "<br>" + 
                                                                                                     "<br>" +
                                "Project Name:   "  + Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name + "<br>" +
                                "File Name:      "  + sf.GetFileName()                             + "<br>" +
                                "Class Name:     "  + sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType                 + "<br>" +
                                "Method Name:    "  + sf.GetMethod()                               + "<br>" +
                                "Line Number:    "  + sf.GetFileLineNumber()                       + "<br>" +
                                "Line Column:    "  + sf.GetFileColumnNumber()                     + "<br>" +
                                "Error Message:  "  + Ex.Message                                   + "<br>" +
                                "Inner Message : "  + Ex.InnerException.Message                    + "<br>";

    return OutputHTML;
}
```

On any entry points in your library that can end up wanting to log the project name, you'd have to record the calling assembly and mark it `NoInlining`, then pass that around internally.

If you're using .NET 4.5, there's an alternative way to do this: [`CallerFilePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx). It has the same restrictions on entry points, and it returns the source path on your machine instead of the assembly name (which is probably less useful), but it's easier to know that it'll work (because it compiles it, just like optional parameters are compiled in), and it allows inlining:

```
public static string JndGetEmailTextForDebuggingExceptionError
              (this Exception Ex, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "")
{
    StackFrame sf = Ex.JndGetStackFrame();

    string OutputHTML =         "<i><b><u>For Developer Use Only: </u></b></i>" + "<br><br>" +
                                "Source File Path:   "  + filePath + "<br>" +
...
```

Comment: Depending on how he's invoking the code, that is not likely to work.  If he's running in an error handler, the calling assembly will either be `System.Web` or his logging assembly.

Comment: @SLaks at any `public` entry point(s) to his library of error handling code, he should record `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` (and then pass that around internally as needed). Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @J-CSharper, what assembly name did you get? And what assembly contains the method that calls `JndGetEmailTextForDebuggingExceptionError`?

Comment: Hold one a minute. Let me retry.

Comment: It works. Thanks Tim, sorry I didn't test it correct first time.Thanks you all for your support. You're the best code support forum I ever step into.

Comment: @J-CSharper: Note that this will not work if you initialize via `WebActivator` or `PreApplicationStartMethod`

Comment: Do I need to deploy .pdb together with exe file in order to have it working?

Comment: @SLaks is that only if you get an error during those times? Otherwise, I don't see how it can affect it: whatever's above it on the stack, it was called from that certain place. Anyway, I've added an alternate approach, using `CallerFilePath`, which should work regardless of that sort of stuff.

Comment: @J-CSharper I don't think so.

Comment: @TimS.: Neither of those will work.  My point is that the caller of this method (or the setup method) may not be the user's project.  Instead, it might be WebActivator, the ASP.Net error handling stack, or the ASP.Net initialization stack.

Comment: how do you get JndGetStackFrame?

Answer (score 38):

For anyone looking for an ASP.NET Core compatible solution, the following should work;

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

[.NET Core API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.reflection.assembly#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetEntryAssembly)

Answer (score 15):

This ought to be enough

```
string projectName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Edit* If you are running this from another assembly then you should use [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) instead.

Comment: That is unlikely to be good enough;  his logging code is probably (hopefully) in a separate library assembly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name
```

If this returns `App_global.asax....`, change it to

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().BaseType.Assembly.GetName().Name
```

If you aren't running in an HTTP request, you will need some way to get ahold of the `HttpContext`.

This will return different results if you're in a Web Site project (as opposed to Web Application).

You can also use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` to get the physical path on disk to the deployed site; this will work everywhere.

Comment: This gave me `System.Web` when running under a project named `WebApplication1`..?

Comment: @dtsg: Does the project have an `HttpApplication` descendant registered in Global.asax?

Comment: This is a new project with no `Global.asax` file

Comment: @dtsg: That would explain it.  AFAIK, all real projects will have a Global.asax.

Comment: Righto. Called this from another assembly (your second example) and it returns `App_global.asax.xw877d4c`?

Comment: @dtsg: The `BaseType` was in an `App_global.asax` assembly? That's strange.  It may be necessary to keep getting `BaseType` until you escape from that.

Comment: Second option worked great to access resource file string when we don't know project name at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

Reflection is the best way to find out product name,company name version like information.

```
public static string ProductName
{
 get
 {
    AssemblyProductAttribute myProduct =(AssemblyProductAttribute)AssemblyProductAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
     typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute));
      return myProduct.Product;
  }
}
```

And Another way like get direct project name

```
string projectName=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString();
```

Comment: That won't work if it's in a separate assembly (which is likely)

Comment: Also, ASP.Net projects are not very likely to have this attribute.

Comment: Works fine in ASP.NET if single assembly

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my answer here.

For those who work with multiple Dlls in their projects, the correct answer is:

```cs
string projectName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[0];
```